# Error detected while processing /home/kiran/.vimrc:

Tags: command-line, vi

I m getting an error message when I am opening vi editor.
the error message is here.

```
kiran@kiran-HP:~/Desktop$ vi hello.c
Error detected while processing /home/kiran/.vimrc:
line    1:
E481: No range allowed: $ set nocompatible
line    2:
E481: No range allowed: $ set backspace=2
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

I'm new to Ubuntu and this terminal. please help.

Comment: Delete the `$ ` before those lines in `~/.vimrc`.

Answer (score 1):

There are stray `$` characters in your `.vimrc`. Run this command to clean them up:

```
sed -.bak 's/^[$]//' ~/.vimrc
```

You can also do this manually by `vim ~/.vimrc`. After `vim` shows the error message, press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to continue.